# Flutter AutoRoute Issue: Blank Screen and Data Loss on Browser Refresh

Tags: flutter

I'm encountering a perplexing issue in my Flutter project where I'm using the AutoRoute package for routing. The problem arises when I navigate to different routes within my app, and then decide to refresh the browser. Upon doing so, I'm faced with a black screen, and sometimes even experience data loss and my route history.

I would appreciate any assistance or insights on how to resolve this issue. It's crucial for me to ensure that my app remains stable and responsive, even after a browser refresh.

Please note that I can't add universal_html to the project, as the app is intended for Android and iOS platforms as well. If you've encountered a similar problem or have expertise in Flutter's AutoRoute, please share your thoughts and potential solutions. Your help will be greatly appreciated!

auto_route version:

```
dependencies:
  auto_route: ^5.0.2
dev_dependencies:
  auto_route_generator: ^5.0.2
  build_runner: ^2.3.3
```

flutter version:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.2, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.83.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```